# How can I display the username of a user currently logged in to our web site?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory

I am using ColdFusion 9.1.2.

Our intranet users are currently logging in to a workstation via Active Directory.  I want our ColdFusion intranet page to display their Active Directory username.

Are there Active Directory variables available to ColdFusion? How do I access them?

Comment: Have you checked the CGI scope? You might be able to get the auth_user in there.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I didn't display all CGI though. I'll check that out again. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/cold-fusion/15060/Pass-current-login-name-to-coldfusion
>
> Mattastic - 24 Jul 2007 09:53 GMT
>
> If you have integrated authentication enabled in IIS, CGI.AUTH_USER
>   will be set  to the DOMAIN\username of the current user.

I haven't done it before, but this seems to be the answer.

Comment: I will be trying to implement this next week. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the tip!